# How do I make a numpy array with the (y, x) coordinates as values?

Tags: python, numpy

The array should be like this:

```
[[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3]],
 [[1,0], [1,1], [1,2], [1,2]],
 [[2,0], [2,1], [2,2], [2,2]]]
```

My attempt(very inefficient):

```
coord = np.empty((height, width, 2))
for h in range(height):
    for w in range(width):
        for z in range(2):
            coord[h][w][z] = h if z == 0 else w
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
import numpy as np
height=3
width=4
x=np.arange(height)
y=np.arange(width)
coord=np.stack(np.meshgrid(y,x)[::-1], axis=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

what do you call inefficient?

Have you tried list comprehension?

```
height = 3
width = 4
[[[i,j] for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.indices` to generate the array, then you will need to transpose it properly to get the required behavior:

```
x = np.indices((3,4)).T
x =list(map(list, zip(*x)))
```

A better approach:

```
x = np.indices((4,3))
x = np.array((x[1],x[0])).T
```